# Ajax freezes up the website for 3-5 minutes

Tags: html, ajax

My goal for this ajax is to have it so that when something changes in the database, the screen will change from no to yes. I have this successfully working but if I leave it up for a few minutes it will crash the website, and any other site i'm hosting, for about 3 minutes. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function get(){
$.post('getdone.php', {}, 
    function(output){
    if(output)$('#age').html('YES').show(); 
    else if(!output)$('#age').html('NO').show();    
    }
)   
setTimeout('get()',1000);
}

</script>
```

and then for html

```
<body onload="get();">
<div id="age">result</div>
```

Here is getdone.php

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("****", "*****", "******")or die("nope") ;
mysql_select_db("******");
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pat WHERE given='1'"))!=0)echo "given_recieved";
$query2=mysql_query("UPDATE pat SET given='0' WHERE given='1'");
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: check that everything is fine server side, in `getdone.php`..

Comment: It is. everything works fine, its just the freezing that is the problem.

Comment: if the website (server) crashes I think the problem is server side.. can you post the php code?

Comment: What's that PHP doing? It could be occurring in the php. The fact that the problem only lasts a few minutes could be that the php is putting the web server in a bad state and the server is recycling itself. As BeNdErR has requested, you should probably post the php code.

Comment: Ok I posted the php file

Comment: Consider using `SELECT COUNT(*)` for a more efficient query. Also, you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`. The old `mysql` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Everything is still freezing up

Comment: is there something i'm not closing or some process that I need to end?